# How to read Adobe Photoshop files, and grab the layer names/group names?

Tags: parsing, converters, psd

Ok so I have been browsing and looking all over the place for a suitable answer to my dilemma and so far I have only found 1/2 a solution. Which is here : http://www.graphicsmill.com/photoshop-psd

My question in short is how would i allow an upload of a PSD/AI file, grab the layer/group names, layer styles,etc and take that information and fill it into a required section of the product im building. First off due to NDA clauses I cannot discuss the entire matter in full but do have permission to seek out help here.

The ultimate goal of what i need to do is to grab the information inside the file and use it in other places. For example if a layer is named  i need to take that information and register it as a valid  in the product. It doesn't matter what language i need to use because the only one I am not familiar with is Ruby.

When opening an PSD/AI file through a text editor or IDE you can see the file name(s) such as this : App. So how would I, and what language should i use to read the file, grab the layer name and take that information and use it elsewhere.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be incredibly helpful, or if this has been answered elsewhere as well it would be incredibly helpful.

Please keep in mind that what ever language i should use has to be able to registered on the front end of a web page, as in allow the uploading process etc.

Thanks again!

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I answer your question fully, but hopefuly this will help you out:

First off, You might be able to get what you want with Photoshop scripting, Which is JavaScript. Actually it's ExtendScript which is near enough the same thing. This might not be you're ideal solution as you probably just want to parse the psd. Like I said this may point you in the right direction.

Secondly, Make the files local.  It's easier in a script for Photoshop to peek at layer names that way. If that isn't suitable then you're gonna have to ask a grown-up for help.

Thirdly, Photoshop doesn't make things easy when you have group layers, you have to have a recursive function that loops over all the layers before you can get what you want. This can be slow on large PSD files.

For a simple PSD with only a couple of layers use:

```
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

// main loop
for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0  ; i--)
{
  var thisLayer = srcDoc.layers[i];
  doStuff(thisLayer);
}

function doStuff(alayer)
{
  // do stuff!
  alert(alayer.name)
}
```

That was straight forward - you can just add your layernames to an array as you go.
As for more complex PSD files you're gonna need the recursive function:

```
// group layer vegetables
var allLayers = new Array();
var theLayers = collectAllLayers(app.activeDocument, 0);

function doStuff(alayer)
{
  // do stuff!
  alert(alayer.name)
}


// function collect all layers
function collectAllLayers (theParent, level)
{
  for (var m = theParent.layers.length - 1; m >= 0; m--)
  {
    var theLayer = theParent.layers[m];
    // apply the function to layersets;
    if (theLayer.typename == "ArtLayer")
    {
      // find the art layers
      doStuff(theLayer)
    }
    else
    {
      allLayers.push(level + theLayer.name);
      collectAllLayers(theLayer, level + 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! First off though, the uploading will be all client side, not server side. The sizes of some designs exceed over 1gb or more. So it will be all client side. You answer has given me some new insight, but not fully what I am looking for or havent already tried. mostly i need to grab layer names,colors,styles, for instance <header> tag and then take that information and have the product register that as a <header>.